# Pulling in a header HTML content from S3 into React App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-redux

We have a React App that requires header and footer content from a shared place, on AWS S3.

Is it possible to dynamically include HTML from S3 into a React App? Furthermore, what is the best way to cache this content? Should we have an API that handles serving the content and then cache the response or do this from within React?

How does this work as not being a component itself and rather surrounding the entire app?

Comment: check this https://dev.to/drews256/build-a-simple-static-site-on-amazon-s3-1nld

Comment: I understand the concept of hosting content/sites on S3. This is specifically regarding includes some custom HTML into a React App